# Parse Error with my API

Tags: php

I'm getting the following message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''; '
>   (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\SQLBackupTool\index.php
>   on line 15

With the following code:

```
    $mysqlExportPath = "C:\xampp\htdocs\SQLBackupTool\{$Schema}.sql";
    $command='C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump -u '.$DB_Usr.' -p'.$DB_Pswd.' '.$Schema.' > C:\xampp\htdocs\tt\'.$Schema.'.sql'; <-- Problematic Code
    file_put_contents("SQLBackup.bat",$command."\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

It all looks normal to me.. But apparently it's wrong, and after researching I cannot find the issue, even with the syntax highlighting. I have closed all the necessary quotes and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of String concatenation, you will need to double escape your backslash `\\` for it to be parsed correctly.

So your working code should be:

```
$command='C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump -u '.$DB_Usr.' -p'.$DB_Pswd.' '.$Schema.' > C:\xampp\htdocs\tt\\'.$Schema.'.sql';
```